# Present Perfect Tense vs Past Perfect Tense

Tags: tense, present-perfect, past-perfect, present-tense

> 1).  Something has happened in the past twenty years that surely must transcend anything that **has** happened before.

> 2). Something has happened in the past twenty years that surely must transcend anything that **had** happened before.

Which one is correct ? If both are correct, what is the difference in meaning between these two sentences?

Comment: Be consistent, you're comparing *what **has** happened [just **now**]* with *what **has** happened [before / up until **now**]*. That's to say *the current "narrative reference time" is **now** [time of utterance].*

Comment: (*She **has** eaten before he **had** eaten* is a syntactically invalid mixture of tenses.)

Answer (score 1):

For me, neither sentence reads very well.  Personally, I would not use either.

If the intention is to compare the "something" with things that happened *before* 20 years ago, then I would not use either:

- Something has happened in the past twenty years that surely must transcend anything that happened before.

If the intention is to compare the "something" with other things that happened in the past twenty years, then I would use:

- Something has happened in the past twenty years that surely must transcend anything else.